# Adding child view at runtime causes it to hide the toolbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have this `Coordinator` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
    android:background="#333">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/whats_new" />

                <include
                    layout="@layout/discover_movies_button" />

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Everything is displayed correctly when I run it.

However I want to add the `whats_new` layout manually, at runtime.
So I removed it from the above XML code and add it like:

```
final LinearLayout mainContentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content_layout);
final View whatsNewView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.whats_new, mainContentLayout, false);
mainContentLayout.addView(whatsNewView, 0);
```

But now the `whats_new` layout partially hides the toolbar... I understand this has something to do with the Coordinator layout, but I have no idea how it can be fixed.